# Variance of two correlated variables

Tags: variance

Suppose X and Y are two correlated random variables, and var(X), cov(X,Y) are 
known. Is there a unique solution for var(Y) and can we determine var(Y) by only
using var(X) and cov(X,Y)?

Comment: Consider using `self-study` tag since this seems to be homework exercise.

Comment: The above equation is Corr(X,Y)=Cov(X,Y)/(Sdt(X)*Sdt(Y)). It implies that if Corr(X,Y), Cov(X,Y) and Var(X) is given, then a unique Var(Y) is obtained. If corr(X,Y) is not known, Var(Y) cannot be determined. So my question is that if only Cov(X,Y) and Var(X) are known, the solution is not unique but multiple for Var(Y) which corresponds to different Corr(X,Y). Is it correct?

Comment: More comments. Suppose X and Y are random variables with zero mean and joint normal distribution N(0, sigma_1^2, sigma_2^2, rho_{12}. In this case Var(X)=sigma_1^2, and Cov(X,Y)=sigma_1*sigma_2*rho_{12}. Since Cov(X,Y) already gives sigma_2, the Var(Y) has been uniquely defined as sigma_2^2. So Var(X) and Cov(X,Y) are sufficient to determine the unique Var(Y). My question is whether this is true for an arbitrary joint distribution?

Comment: @GL38, you are right. If you don't know VAR(X+Y) or Corr(X,Y), then multiple solutions exist. It's like triangles in geometry. In your case you know two sides, but no angles, so many triangles would fit. If you knew correlation, it would be like knowing the angle.

Comment: Aksakal, is there any other way to determine corr(X,Y)?

Comment: -1 for the _repeated_ nonsensical assertion that for zero-mean jointly normal random variables, var$(X)$ and cov$(X,Y)$ uniquely determine var$(Y)$.

Answer (score 7):

For a bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$, the only constraint on the triplet $\text{var}(X),\text{var}(Y),\text{cov}(X,Y)$ is that the matrix
$$\Sigma=\left( \begin{matrix} \text{var}(X) &\text{cov}(X,Y)\\ \text{cov}(X,Y)&\text{var}(Y)\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$
be positive semidefinite; *i.e.,* $$\text{det}(\Sigma) \ge 0, \text{var}(X)\ge 0, \text{var}(Y)\ge 0;$$ or (since clearly $\text{var}(X)\ge 0$ and $\text{var}(Y)\ge 0$)
$$\text{var}(X)\text{var}(Y)-\text{cov}(X,Y)^2\ge 0.$$
There is therefore no way to derive $\text{var}(Y)$ uniquely from $\text{var}(X),\text{cov}(X,Y)$.

[image: Figure]

*The solid region bounded below by the surface shows a portion of the possible triples $(\text{var}(X), \text{cov}(X,Y), \text{var}(Y))$ consistent with these constraints.*

Comment: But we do get a constraint: $$\operatorname{var}(Y) \geq \frac{\left(\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\right)^2}{\operatorname{var}(X)}$$ which is some improvement over the more generic $\operatorname{var}(Y) \geq 0$.

Comment: @Dilip That's right--but it's better to leave it in the form in which Xi'an presented it, because your form is invalid when $\text{var}(X)=0$.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality var(X)var(Y)>=cov(X,Y)^2 does not result a general conclusion: given var(X) and cov(X,Y), there is therefore no way to derive var(Y) uniquely from var(X),cov(X,Y). As I mentioned before, for random variables X and Y with zero mean and joint normal distribution, it satisfies the relation: var(X)*var(Y)=sigma_x^2*sigma_y^2 >= cov(X,Y)^2=sigma_x^2sigma_y^2rho_{xy}^2 because -1<= rho_{xy}<=1, but given var(X) and cov(X,Y), var(Y) is uniquely defined. –  GL38 just now   edit

Comment: @GL38 Your assertion that for _zero-mean_ _jointly normal_ random variables, knowledge of var$(X)$ and cov$(X,Y)$ uniquely determines var$(Y)$ is not correct.

Comment: If the surface given by Xi'an is correct, then the conclusion is that given var(X) and cov(X,Y) uniquely determines a var(Y). Because given a var(X) is an intersection between a plane with fixed value of var(X) and the surface, which gives a curve. Then given a cov(X,Y) is an intersection between a plane with a fixed value of cov(X,Y) with the curve, which results a point.

Comment: @GL38 The surface (provided by whuber in an edit) is the **boundary** of a solid region that contains all possible points (var(X),var(Y),cov(X,Y)$. The point **does not have to lie on the surface** as you insist.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. But how do you explain the fact that I mentioned, the system of X,Y with zero mean and a joint normal distribution? Given var(X)=sigma_x^2, and cov(X,Y)=sigma_x^2*sigma_y^2*rho_{xy}^2 uniquely defines var(Y)=sigma_y^2?

Comment: And the nonsensical insistence that for zero-mean jointly normal random variables, knowledge of var$(X)$ and cov$(X,Y)$ suffices to determine var$(Y)$ continues. @GL38 Regardless of what you believe, cov(X,Y) **does not** equal sigma_x^2*sigma_y^2*rho_{xy}^2; cov(X,Y) equals sigma_x^2*sigma_y^2*rho_{xy}, and even then, knowing the values of cov(X,Y) and sigma_x^2 tells you only what the value of sigma_y^2*rho_{xy} is: **it does not tell you what sigma_y^2 is.**  Sheesh!